# turn off and turn on Esp wifi using WiFiManager library

Tags: c++, c, arduino, embedded

Using ESP wifi occupies 1 of its ADC converter which I don't want to happen, so I am using **WiFi.mode(WIFI_OFF);** to turn off wifi reading some analog value than want to upload them using wifi but how to start wifi again on request?
I have used **WiFi.mode(STA);** but it didn't work. how can I turn on wifi again? I am using **WiFiManager Library**.

Comment: `WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA)`

Answer (score 0):

Turn your wifi off like this:

```
WiFi.mode(WIFI_OFF);
WiFi.forceSleepBegin();
delay(1);
```

Turn it on again:

```
WiFi.forceSleepWake();
WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);  
wifi_station_connect();
WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
```

But if I look the code, you can find that the wifi_station_connect(); is already in WiFi.begin(); So you could wait a little:

```
WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) delay(500);
```

Comment: I am using the WiFiManager Library library this library does not support these commands they work fine with the WiFi.h library